# Segmentation fault on reverse string function

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a simple function which reverses a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* reverseStr(char*s)
{
    int sLen=strlen(s);
    int i;
    char temp;

    for (i=0;i<(sLen/2);i++)
    {
         //swap
         temp=s[i];
         s[i]=s[sLen-i-1];
         s[sLen-i-1]=temp;
    }
    return s;
}
main()
{
    int num=64;
    char*str;
    str[0]='a';
    *(str+1)='b';
    *(str+2)='\0';
    printf("%s %d %s" ,str,strlen(str),reverseStr(str));
}
```

When I call this function for some reason I get the Segmentation fault Core Dumped error.
I can't spot the place where it caused.
Anyone?

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: show your caller of this function

Comment: `str[0]='a'`, here `str` is not allocated memory.

Comment: `char*str;` not allocated memory. change to `char str[3];`

Comment: **-Wall** : `warning: 'str' is used uninitialized in this function`

Comment: also Split `printf("%s %d %s" ,str,strlen(str),reverseStr(str));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies in how you're creating the string in the first place:

```
char*str;
str[0]='a';
*(str+1)='b';
*(str+2)='\0';
```

The declaration of `str` gives it an *arbitrary* value so that dereferencing it with `str[0]` is undefined behaviour.

You can fix it with something like:

```
char str[3];
str[0]='a';
*(str+1)='b';
*(str+2)='\0';
```

although I'm not sure why you're *mixing* the dereferencing methods (`base[idx]` and `*(base+idx)`).

Alternatively, you could try the more concise options of:

```
char str[3]; strcpy (str, "ab");
char str[] = "ab";
```

Comment: `char str[] = "ab";` would be the most idiomatic I feel

Comment: OMG you're right. I mess with the memory allocation all the time. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You did not allocate memory where you are trying to place character constants 'a', 'b'and '\0'.

Either write

```
char str[] = "ab";
```

or

```
char *str = malloc( 3 * sizeof( char ) );

str[0]='a';
*(str+1)='b';
*(str+2)='\0';

//...

free( str );
```

Also this statement

```
printf("%s %d %s" ,str,strlen(str),reverseStr(str));
```

has undefined behaviour because the order of evaluation of function parameters is unspecified. Rewrite it as

```
printf("%s %zu " ,str,strlen(str));
printf("%s" , reverseStr(str));
```

Take into account that function `strlen` has return type `size_t`

Answer (score 1):

Allocating memory to str will solve your problem.

Like

```
char str[3];
```

But I see one more problem in your program.

If you compile and run your program you might not be able to print the initial string "ab".Because the output depends on the order of execution, since you are pasing the string to a function and that function is modifying the string you might end up printing the reverse string twice.
So it is better you print your initial string before calling the function reverseStr()

Comment: You are right and I spotted the problem too when I had no runtime errors. Thanks!